# Load a local file to spark using sc.textFile() using relative address?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How to load a file from the local file system to Spark using `sc.textFile` with a **relative address instead of absolute**? Most examples online use an absolute address that specifies where exactly in filesystem the file is. I want to use relative address because I need to upload this code to github, where other developers can clone and run it on their machines. The absolute addrress will not work since it contains my username but a relative address will.

Ex:

```
val inputFile = sc.textFile("file///C:/Users/swaapnika/Desktop/to do list")
```

but I want

```
val inputFile = sc.textFile("../../folderName/to do list")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can *get the path to the directory where your project* is by using

```
val projectDirectory = new java.io.File(".").getCanonicalPath
```

and then *if your folder in inside your project* then you can do

```
val inputFile = sc.textFile(projectDirectory+"/folderName/to do list")
```